# How should I store this BBQ sauce for later use?

Tags: sauce, freezing, storage-lifetime, barbecue

Dropped by a video where a BBQ sauce caught my attention. The ingredients used are:

```
Olive oil, for frying
1 small onion, peeled and finely diced
2–3 garlic cloves, finely chopped
Sea salt and freshly ground black pepper
1 tbsp brown sugar
1 tsp smoked paprika
1 tbsp cider vinegar
2 tsp Worcestershire sauce
6 tbsp tomato ketchup
```

I was thinking about making larger quantities so that I can use it on sandwiches throughout the week. Two questions came up in the process:

1. Is it safe to assume the sauce will be ok if refrigerated for a week? Can I keep it in the fridge for longer?
2. Would it be a good idea to store such a sauce in the freezer? If yes, for how long until everything goes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's any good, it will be gone long before it goes bad in the refrigerator. :-).

I've saved my homemade barbecue sauce for at least two weeks in the fridge.  Store-bought barbecue sauce lasts for months.  You do need to put it in a sealed container.

Answer (score 1):

Your mixture should have sufficient salt, sugar, and acidity for it to be safe in the refrigerator for 1-2 weeks. Absent any professional canning methods and equipment, I would not trust it beyond that.

There's no reason you should not be able to freeze your sauce. Though you may want to omit he oil, as it will separate. Or you could put an emulsifier like mustard powder into your sauce and blend it heavily, which would also limit separation during freezing.